# Passing Dynamic Filename in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to pass dynamic filename from source to sink in azure data factory.

Steps
i have created a pipeline with 'look up' activity and 'for each' activity
2.in 'For Each' activity have defined a data flow
3.The data flow compares table from 2 database
4.I want to Pass the filename for every iteration from Source to sink.

Attaching data flow:
[image: Data Flow]

Comment: what you are using as source and sink?

Comment: Source :SQL Database. Target-PostgreSQL comparing both  tables and putting the output in SINK container.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to Pass the filename for every iteration from Source to sink.

To pass dynamic value from source to sink

- Open `Source` dataset go to parameters create two parameters for table name and schema name of type string.
  [image]
- Go to connection check the `Edit` checkbox and click on add dynamic value add `@datset().schemaname` for schema name and `@datset().tablename` for table name.
  [image]
- Open `Sink` dataset go to parameters create two parameters for table name and schema name of type string.
  [image]
- Go to connection check the `Edit` checkbox and click on add dynamic value add `@datset().schemaname` for schema name and `@datset().tablename` for table name.
  [image]
- Go to DataFlow  >> `Settings` under the dataflow name expand Sorce parameters and Sink parameters for table name parameter enter `@item().table_name` and for Schema name parameter enter `@item().table_schema` it will take values from foreach activity.
  [image]

**Note: I took Source as SQL database and sink as PostgreSQL**